# How to Set Cryptographic Provider to New-SelfSignedCertificate Properly?

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509certificate

I use Windows 10 and want to create a self-signed certificate with a custom cryptographic provider for my application's test. and here is my script:

```bsh
 New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -Provider "Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0" -Subject "CN=test" -KeyUsage "CertSign", "CRLSign", "DigitalSignature", "NonRepudiation" -KeyExportPolicy Exportable -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(40) -Type Custom
```

but i get this error:

```bsh
New-SelfSignedCertificate : CertEnroll::CX509Enrollment::_CreateRequest: Provider type not defined. 0x80090017 (-2146893801 NTE_PROV_TYPE_NOT_DEF)
At line:1 char:2
+  New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-SelfSignedCertificate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Exception,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.NewSelfSignedCertificateCommand
```

I should use `Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0` as provider (because my testing app only accepts certs with this provider) but got above error. how should i set **Porvider Type** mentioned in error message?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using legacy CSPs, you have to specify `-KeySpec` parameter where you provide the key type: key exchange or signature. Based on your values, it should be `AT_SIGNATURE`, i.e. `-KeySpec 2`.

Answer (score 0):

found answer! it was only worked in Windows Server environment not in my win 10 client!

Comment: you haven't found answer. See my response.